# touch does not update session.cookie.expires using Sequelize Store

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, touch, session-cookies, express-session

I've been struggling with this for a while. I have a server side that creates a session using express-session library. I'm using SequelizeStore to store session records in a local DB. Note, my application is using WS for 99% of all business logic, so there is almost no http requests made to the server.

Here is my session configuration:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(


process.env.DB,
  process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
)

const myStore = new SequelizeStore({
  db: sequelize,
  tableName: 'sessions',
  checkExpirationInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000, // Storage auto cleanup
})

let sess = {
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  store: myStore,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: parseInt(process.env.SESSION_MAXAGE),
    httpOnly: false,
    // sameSite: 'strict'
    domain: process.env.SERVER_NAME,
  },
  name: 'sessionId',
  resave: false, // Touch is enabled via SequelizeStore
  rolling: false, // Force the session identifier cookie to be set on every response.
  saveUninitialized: true,
}

// Use secure cookies in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
  sess.proxy = true // The "X-Forwarded-Proto" header will be used
  sess.sameSite = 'none'
  sess.cookie.secure = true // serve secure cookies
}

app.use(session(sess))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

I also got a custom api route that is being called every minute to verify the session, logged in flag and sid expiration.

The ultimate problem is that when I call req.session.touch() it does not save changes to the session. When I'm sending a response the response header has a cookie with just a sessionId in it. The code below doesn't execute at all as I don't see any logs in the terminal.

```
req.session.touch((err) => {
if (err) {
    console.error('Error touching session:', err)
  } else {
    console.log('Session touched')
    console.log(
      'Session expiration after touch:',
      req.session.cookie.expires,
    )
  }
})
```

Here a full example of my implementation:

```
const verifySession = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Verifying the session')
  const cookies = req.cookies

  if (cookies.sessionId) {
    const sessionId = cookies.sessionId.split('.')[0].split('s:')[1]

    console.log('sessionId on the database - ', req.sessionID)
    console.log('sessionId on the cookie   - ', sessionId)

    if (sessionId === req.sessionID) {
      console.log('100% session ID match')
      next()
    } else {
      console.log('Unauthorized')
      res.status(401).json({status: 'Unauthorized. Bad session'}).end()
    }
  } else {
    req.session.regenerate((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error generating new session:', err)
        res.status(500).json({error: 'Internal server error'})
      } else {
        console.log('New session generated')
        res
          .status(200)
          .json({
            id: null,
            username: null,
            roles: [],
            logged_in: false
          })
      }
    })
  }
}

app.get('/api/check-session', verifySession, async (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.passport && req.session.logged_in) {
    const user = await Users.getUser(req.session.passport.user)

    // Put roles in the array
    const userRoles = []
    user.Roles.forEach((element) => userRoles.push(element.role_name))    

    console.log('touching the session')
    console.log('Session expiration before touch:', req.session.cookie.expires)
    console.log(req.session)
    req.session.touch((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error touching session:', err)
      } else {
        console.log('Session touched')
        console.log(
          'Session expiration after touch:',
          req.session.cookie.expires,
        )
      }
    })

    res.status(200).json({
      id: user.user_id,
      username: user.username,
      roles: userRoles,
      logged_in: req.session.logged_in,
    })
    // })
  } else {
    if (!req.cookies.sessionId) {
      // Generate a new session if the session cookie is not present
      req.session.regenerate((err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error generating new session:', err)
          res.status(500).json({error: 'Internal server error'})
        } else {
          console.log('New session generated')
          res.status(200).json({
            id: null,
            username: null,
            roles: [],
            logged_in: false,
          })
        }
      })
    } else {
      // User is not logged in, but session cookie is present, continue with existing session

      // Check if the session has expired
      console.log('Check if the session has expired')
      console.log(new Date(req.session.cookie.expires).getTime())
      console.log(Date.now())
      console.log(
        req.session.cookie.expires && req.session.cookie.expires <= Date.now(),
      )

      const buffer = 1000 // 1-second buffer

      if (
        req.session.cookie.expires &&
        new Date(req.session.cookie.expires).getTime() <= Date.now() + buffer
      ) {
        // Session has expired, regenerate it
        console.log('Session has expired, regenerate it')
        req.session.regenerate((err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error generating new session:', err)
            res.status(500).json({error: 'Internal server error'})
          } else {
            console.log('Session expired and regenerated')
            res.status(200).json({
              id: null,
              username: null,
              roles: [],
              logged_in: false,
            })
          }
        })
      } else {
        // Session is still valid, continue with existing session
        console.log('Session is still valid, continue')
        res.status(200).json({
          id: null,
          username: null,
          roles: [],
          logged_in: false,
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I chose to have rolling to be set to false as I have a complex case managing sessions/ws connections. What am I doing wrong with current implementation and how to make my session cookie to have an updated expiration on response?